# how to connect to SQL Server with SQuirreL SQL from non domain registered Linux box?

Tags: sql-server, linux, dns, squirrel-sql

I need to connect to a SQL 2008 R2 Server from my Linux box that's not registered in my company's domain. I'm trying to use SQuirreL SQL version 3.2.1.
I downloaded [Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21599) and assigned it to SQuirreL on the Drivers tab.

Now, when I try to create an Alias on SQuirreL, I select the SQL Server driver and adjust the URL. For credentials I use my domain registered username and password.

When I try to test the connection, I always get the same error:

<"database-name">: Logon failure for user '<"domain">\<"domain-user">'.

How can I get this working? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I got rid of Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver and downloaded [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/index.html) driver. I tweaked a bit with it until I finally got a successful connection. The correct connection string was:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server_ip>:1433;databaseName=<instance_name>;domain=<domain_name>
```

Comment: I spent about 2 hours trying to get connected. After 5 minutes of jTDS it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

The answer may be obsolete as I had the similar problem with SQuirrel SQL on MacOS 10.9.3 not on Linux box. The way Peter solved the problem inspired me. As the solution was not most straightforward I decided to put it here. Hope it helps someone.

1. Download latest Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server (tar.gz package)
2. Extract only sqljdbc4.jar from the package
3. Copy the jar file into Squirrel SQL (Contents->Resources->Java->Lib)
4. Now Microsoft MSSQL Server JDBC Driver is available to create Alias
5. Connection URL: jdbc:sqlserver://SERVERNAME;databaseName=DATABASENAME

Comment: Just in case it happens to others... The MS driver download page, when accessed over https, fails to start the download in Chrome (44 as of writing). To get the download to start, go to the page over http and try again.

Answer (score 7):

Another solution that worked for me. On a Windows desktop connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2, I had to follow these steps:

- copy the **jtds-1.3.1.jar** into the SQuirrel SQL \lib directory
- restart SQuirrel SQL and check that you see **jTDS Microsoft SQL** in the drivers list
- make sure that in the driver configuration the Class Name specifies **net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver**
- use a connection string like this

`jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<hostnameOrIp>:<port>/<databaseName>;instance=<instanceName>`

Comment: This solution was the easiest for me. I would only add that you need to get a copy of jtds. Currently (Oct 2018) the it's hosted on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/)

Comment: When changing the driver config class name as shown, I get error - Could not find class net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver in neither the Java class path nor the Extra class path of the jTDS Microsoft SQL driver definition:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to connect to an SQL Server from SQuirrel on a linux box.  Rough* steps ...

- You only need one of the jdbc jars from the MS download (copied to 'lib')
- Must use SQL Server auth (not windows network auth)
- SQL Server auth was already enabled on our db
- Added a login 'jdoe'
- Set jdoe default database to 'XxxDb'
- Added a 'User Mapping' from jdoe to the desired database
- Set up permission on the SQL Server for jdoe: 'Connect' and 'View any database'
- Connection string: jdbc:sqlserver://SERVERNAME:1433;databaseName=XxxDb

* May not need all as I poking around

Answer (score 1):

For you to connect to MS SQL Server you need to obtain the JDBC drivers:

- [Download latest Microsoft JDBC Driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54670)
- Choose to download the `.tar.gz` package
- Extract the package
- In Squirrel-SQL click on Drivers tab on the left side of the window
- Right click on `Microsoft MSSQL Server JDBC Driver` and choose `Modify Driver...`
- Click on `Extra Class Path`
- Click on `Add`
- Browse to where `sqljdbc41.jar` is located (it should be under sqljdbc_4.1/enu/jre7/sqljdbc41.jar or similar) and click on `Open`
- Click on `OK`
- Now to the left of `Microsoft MSSQL Server JDBC Driver` in the Drivers list there should be a check mark which means that you installed the driver correctly

To connect to MS SQL Server:

- Click on the `Aliases` tab on the left side of the window
- Click on the `+` sign to `Create a new Alias`
- Type a name for your new connection
- In the URL text box paste the JDBC connection string (Azure gives this to you under connection strings for example)
- enter username and password
- click on test to see if the connection can be established
- if test was successful then click on `OK` to finish creating your connection

If you are having any issues with connecting to Azure SQL database you might need to give access to your specific IP to connect to it or some similar access privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Microsoft jdbc driver is compatible with your java runtime version you're using,

I was trying to use Driver 6.0 with java-9 and i got this error:
ClassNotFoundException:javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
when i downgraded to version Java SE Runtime Environment 8u101
it connected without problems.